# Are there Unchained data sources for PCGen?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pcgen

Is there a datasource for PCGen available from anywhere that includes the Pathfinder Unchained variants?

Comment: I hope so, but I can't even find a working one for Advanced Class Guide, so I am not optimistic.  Sorry.

Comment: ACG should be out in the next alpha either tuesday or wed. Check out the alpha build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**

Since this question was posted, the PCGen team has added Pathfinder Unchained

from http://pcgen.org/2015/12/12/pcgen-6-05-06-beta-released/

```
PCGen 6.05.06 Beta Released!
Posted on December 12, 2015 by nylanfs — 18 Comments    
The following new sources were added in 6.05.06
...
[Pathfinder] Pathfinder Unchained
```